# find ip address in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to add geolocation on my site so i will get customer current location for that i want ip address which i did not get.

```
<?php include('doctype.php');?>
<header>
  <?php include('topHeader.php');?>
  <?php include('searchArea.php');?>

</header>
<?php include('nav.php');?>
<div class="container">
  <section>
<?php  
$b=get_client_ip();
echo $b;
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
     if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}?>
  </section>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php');?>
```

this is my code i tried to get ip address for geolocation. did you know any geolaction example to get customer current city.

Comment: i get i ip address in this format fe80::9cdc:7d2f:aa09:6e0f

Comment: You can use `$this->input->ip_address()` [method](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::ip_address) instead of that block of code shown.

Answer (score 0):

Best way of get current location using geolocation

Use below get the client current location Latitude & Longitude

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="getlocation()">

<script>

function getlocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
   alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "\n Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This latitude and longitude based display google map marker